# Images does not load in Chrome but they load in safari fine

Tags: html, image, css, google-chrome

So after creating the framework of my HTML site, i included images in the file which loads perfectly fine in Safari but they wont load in Chrome or IE.  what could be causing this?

I tried clearing the cache and cookies but they still wont load.  When the site appears, all that it loads is the alt description of the image.

www.dfwonsitework.com/html

Comment: Are you sure? it works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/HywdGsa.png

Comment: Hi!  All the pictures are loading fine for you?

Comment: what could be causing my chrome and IE to not load them?

Comment: @Bitz thanks for your reply.  all pictures are loading fine for you?  what coudl be causing my Chrome and IE to not load?

Comment: I checked `http://www.dfwonsitework.com/html/images/img-3.jpg` and it seems like the image may be corrupted in some way. Maybe reuploading them or confirming they show up fine on your desktop before uploading them may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image are psd (photoshop format) probably saved with the wrong extension.
Safari is able to load psd format but other browser no.

Comment: I did edit photos in photoshop but i resaved them in photoshop as .jpg or png.   could this be causing the issue?

Comment: For what i see, probably you save the image with the correct extensions (jpg or png) but the format is psd. When you save in photoshop in the saving windows if you select an old file to rewrite it with the modification, ps select the name and the extension but down in this window you have to change ti file format. For example: http://www.projectwoman.com/uploaded_images/3-770630.jpg

Comment: This was the problem!  What an oversight lol

Answer (score 0):

The image given in the link: http://www.dfwonsitework.com/html/images/img-3.jpg is corrupted

Comment: thank you, do you know how i can correct the image that is corrupted?  or what can be causing this image to be corrupted?